# HTML entity in JavaScript (XML and PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

Newbie in troubles again))) Need yr help guys!

I have an XML file with the data like this:

```
<Page>
<Content>&lt;p&gt;Article content&lt;/p&gt;&#13;
&#13;
&lt;h1 style="font-style: italic;"&gt;HEADER&lt;/h1&gt;&#13;
&#13;
&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&#13;
&#13;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;img alt="" src="/upload/images/1.JPG" style="height:51px; width:144px" /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#13;
</Content>
</Page>
```

now I want to extract this data via PHP & replace html by jQ.

```
<?php
$file = '111.xml';
$XML = simplexml_load_file($file);
$str =$XML->Content;
$str = htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES);
JS('var CONV = "'.$str.'"'); //JS function just puts its parametr between <script... tags
echo $str;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#debug").html().text(CONV);
</script>
```

so the result is NOTHING... if i do Echo - it works, if i replace CONV value with smth like "bla bla bla" - it works either. But with encoded or decoded HTML it shows none...

UPDATE:
i still dont know where's the problem. I use "buffer" file as a temporary soultion:

```
file_put_contents('../plugins/'.pl_DIR().'/buffer.db', $str, LOCK_EX);
JS('$("#editor").load("../../plugins/"+PATH+"/buffer.db")');
```

Via AJAX the content loads perfectly but anyway Im sure that's diffenetley not the best idea...

Answer (score 1):

You should try replace

```
$str = htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

with

```
$str = htmlspecialchars_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

I had similar problem the other day, and that solved it for me.

Comment: Thanks! but unfortunatley this doesn't work for me for some reason :( After i do 'JS('var CONV = "'.$str.'"');' It says CONV is undefined in log.

Comment: So you got the result printing anyhow, now you just have to fetch $str with jquery. You could do a ajax-post instead and just return $str. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/